# How to delay second interview?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, email, student

I worked as a software developer and then decided to go back to and finish the university and finally get my degree. Now, I am in the last semester of my studies. I study full-time for my exams and I finish in June. I wanted to start going to interviews at the end of May and to work in August. Today, we are in March.

One of my former colleagues contacted me and said, she was really happy with her new company and that I'd fit in the team really well. I looked up the company online, and I was still unsure what they exactly do and I couldn't imagine how a typical project would look like, so I went to the first interview and I really liked what I saw. They invited me to the second interview, stating they were really satisfied with the work I have done so far, too. However, as I learn all day, it's difficult to show them my best without risking the success of my exams.

**How do I delay the second interview, while minimizing the risk of making them feel as if I were not really interested (or just cancel the whole interview process altogether)? I need at least a month delay.**

I didn't interview for a specific position, the company seems to be growing and it appears that they are constantly hiring if they find a good match. The company knows that I can only start in August and that I'm studying for my exams in May-June.

Comment: How far away is this company from your university? Can you explain why you feel you can't take 1 day off, or 2 days if it's further away, to interview? In my experience, instructors understand when students near graduation may need some time off to attend interviews if their schedule is extremely full, but it seems odd to not have enough time to go for an interview if you are serious about the job.

Comment: Can't you just contact them to explain to them why you need a month delay. If you tell them you want to focus on your study and don't want to do a bad job I think they will appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want to delay the second interview because you feel like you need to prepare for it? Personally, I would just go on it.... The company already knows you can't start until August, so at least going on the interview, I could get hired with a later start date. But if I delay the interview, I'd be worried that they would hire someone without waiting for me.

Comment: I'd like to delay because 1. I need to focus on studying to make 100% sure that I can finish the university this semester (I screwed up some exams before because I tried too many things at once). 2. At the job interview, I need to use Python and the last months I only used C. This caused that now my Python code is not so idiomatic and I need to look up every second method, cause I'm not sure it exists in Python. I think I'd need a couple of days practicing Python, but, unfortunately, I don't have the time for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just talk to them.

If they're a good employer, they'll respect the fact that you're reaching the end of your degree and should allow you to complete that successfully.

If their need to fill that role isn't urgent, then I don't see why they can't wait a while.

Bear in mind that if they find someone else suitable, then you may lose that slot.

But you won't know without talking with them (assuming that for some reason this didn't come up in conversation during your first interview).